# Exported LWJGL-OpenGL Application does not run (Java)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, pong

So I made a clone of pong in Lightweight Java Game Library, by basically following this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0S5Ded2IJY&list=PL513808FE7D9A5D68

Now the thing is: It works absolutely fine from Netbans, but when I build the application into a .jar it just does nothing when I run it. Do I maybe have to reference some natives?

If I run the .jar with cmd, it tells me: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in lwjgl.library.path

In Netbeans the project has -DJava.library.path="NATIVEPATH" as run time parameter.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Edit: I uploaded said .jar so you can test it if you have some time to spend:

http://www.file-upload.net/download-8915614/Pong4.jar.html

Comment: I do not think anyone sane will run the jar executable on their machine. This is a library path issue. Check what are the settings when Netbeans runs your code. Did you also add the lwjgl lib to the path?

Comment: Yeah. Everything from the library is in the build path. Trying to run it with cmd with same run time parameters was also not successful.

Comment: Could you put in the whole cmd line that you try to use to run the code? Together with the file layout there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that java does not know where lwjgl is and therefore cannot use it.

Use [jarsplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) for exporting runnable jars that require libraries and natives (such as ones made with lwjgl)